# Can i continue to writing to a string with printf() after the ','?

Tags: c, string, printf

```
//Assume "char str[n]" declared & initialized
printf("The String \"%s\"",str);
printf("contains %d bytes in RAM", sizeof(str));
```

Is there a way to write this code like in the below Java format in C language?

```
System.out.println("The String " + str + " contains " +  sizeof(str) + " bytes in RAM"); //I know there is no //sizeof(...) in Java, i just wrote it to demonstrate :D
```

Comment: One little bug: the `%d` format specifier expects an argument of type `int`, but `sizeof` yields a value of type `size_t`.  This will work fine on some systems but on others it may break horribly.  You should change `%d` to `%zu`.

Comment: @NateEldredge , thank you for  the detail. I will be careful with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide more than one format specifier and more than one value to `printf()`

```
printf("The String %s contains %d bytes in RAM", str, sizeof(str));
```

As was pointed out in the comments, there's an error in your code. `sizeof(str)` will only give you the size of the variable, not the length of the string. What you're actually looking for is `strlen(str)` instead.

```
printf("The String %s contains %zu in RAM", str, strlen(str));
```

Comment: @Roghan: No problem. You should check the documentation first, though. A search in your favorite search engine for *printf documentation c* can find the documentatino for this function.

Comment: @P: I didn't address other issues in the code. I answered the question asked. I've added that now. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Answering you should explain obvious mistakes made by the very beginner users.

Comment: @P Got it. Didn't pay close enough attention. I do know how to write answers - I'm not new here. :-) I'm not the only one that didn't address the other issue.

Comment: @KenWhite as experienced user you know that `sizeof(str)` and use of `%d` are one of the most frequent questions here. I am especially focused on those common errors as beginners learn from our answers.

Comment: @P: As I said, I didn't really pay attention to the rest of the code. I addressed the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple arguments to `printf`, for example:

```
printf("%d times %d equals %d\n", 3, 5, 3*5);
```

The order of your arguments must match the order in which the formatting specifiers (those starting with `%`) appear in the format string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Sorry i am a newbie. Your answer is working too.